# Is there anyways to do efficient coding in bs4

Tags: python, selenium

```
def parse_table_data(self) -> typing.Union[dict, None]:
    page_source = self.driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
    svg_container = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"scaledRoad--7fdfb"})

    road_result_container = {
        "A": [],
        "B": [],
        "C": [],
        "D": [],
        "E": [],
        "F": [],
    }

    for tn, c in zip(['A','B','C','D','E','F'], svg_container):
        for svg in c.find_all("svg", {"class": "svg--34293"}):
            if svg.has_attr('name') and svg.has_attr('data-type'):
                name = svg['name']
                data_type = svg['data-type']
                if ("Banker" in name or "Player" in name) and data_type == "roadItem":
                    road_result_container[tn].append(name.split(" ")[0])

    return road_result_container
```

this code takes about .5 per one function call. I would like to know how to code efficently with bs4.
I would think of reducing use of for loop or replacing bs4 to another.

Comment: Have you tried [tag:selenium]

Comment: how can I apply [tag: selenium] to my code?  is it actually faster than anyother?

Comment: How about trying it out to reach to a conclusion as you have already tagged [tag:selenium] in your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing

> "html.parser" to "lxml"

really helped me speeding up the code.